# How to get multiple files in one key in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, multipartform-data

I want to parse multiple files in one key in the Rails API.
and this is rails controller code.

```
def fun
  render json: params[:file]
end
```

and this is javascript-jQuery code.

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("file", fileInput.files[0], "75341083_406717103617108_7315677611286331392_n.jpg");
form.append("file", fileInput.files[0], "75380217_961903127500586_7366878762530504704_n.jpg");

var settings = {
  "url": "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "contentType": false,
  "data": form
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

and this is response

```
{
"tempfile": "#<File:0x00007fe4c4a289f0>",
"original_filename": "75380217_961903127500586_7366878762530504704_n.jpg",
"content_type": "image/jpeg",
"headers": "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"75380217_961903127500586_7366878762530504704_n.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n"
}
```

what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the params unique names so that they don't just overwrite each other in the params hash:

```
form.append("file", fileInput.files[0], "75341083_406717103617108_7315677611286331392_n.jpg");
form.append("other_file", fileInput.files[1], "75380217_961903127500586_7366878762530504704_n.jpg");
```

Or create an array in the params:

```
form.append("files[]", fileInput.files[0], "75341083_406717103617108_7315677611286331392_n.jpg");
form.append("files[]", fileInput.files[1], "75380217_961903127500586_7366878762530504704_n.jpg");
```

Or a hash:

```
form.append("files[first]", fileInput.files[0], "75341083_406717103617108_7315677611286331392_n.jpg");
form.append("files[second]", fileInput.files[1], "75380217_961903127500586_7366878762530504704_n.jpg");
```